# Can Pareto Optimality be compared to Nash Equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Given a state $s$, and a value function $v^i$ that determines the expected payoff for the i-th agent in that state, can the two definitions below, one of Nash equilibrium and another of Pareto optimality be compared to one another?

Nash equilibrium:
$$v^i(s, \pi^i_*, \pi^{-i}_*) \ge v^i(s, \pi^i, \pi^{-i}_*)\ \ \  \forall\ \  i \in \{1, 2, \cdots,N\}$$

Pareto optimality:
$$v^i(s, \Pi_\#) \gt v^i(s, \Pi)$$ for atleast 1 agent $i$,
and,

$$v^j(s, \Pi_\#) \ge v^j(s, \Pi)\ \ \  \forall\ \  j \in \{1, 2, \cdots,N\}$$

#### Notation Used

Nash Equlibrium = $(\pi^i_*, \pi^{-i}_*)$

Pareto Optimal stragey = $\Pi_\#$

Answer (score 0):

It can be seen that both concepts are independent in the sense that
a) A Nash equilibrium can be Pareto optimal
b) A Nash equilibrium is not necessarily Pareto optimal
Clarifying your notations would enable us to give a more precise answer